# Selecting data from subquery returning too many rows

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm confident this is a simple matter of framing my understanding, but I'm in a mental block and could use some insight. My query generates too many rows, and I think it's because I'm not using my subqueries correctly. If anyone has a resource to help me straighten it up, I would appreciate it!

**Desired Outcome** A single row selecting a name and *in essence* pivoting single course names onto the same row (when certain data matches).

**Testing Setup** I have to work within the context of existing tables on my development server, but the subqueries correctly create a simple table of enrollment data. For dev purposes, there are no more than two enrollment records that populate in a given subquery, for two different students.

**Output** Block 1 always correctly displays (be it enrollment data or NULL), Block 2 will display either NULL or the correct data, Block 3 will display either NULL or the correct data.

Four rows of data are returned, one with all correct data (Block 1, Block 2, and Block 3) and three with incorrect data (Block 1, NULL, Block 3; Block 1, Block 2, NULL; Block 1, NULL, NULL).

Here's the full code I have so far (with a lot of garbage):

```
select distinct s.lastfirst as "Name", 
    s.home_room as "Teacher", 
    to_char(CASE WHEN (9000000 + satt.student_number) = s.student_number THEN satt.description END) as "School Absence",
    to_char(CASE WHEN s.student_number = satt.student_number THEN satt.description END) as "Extended Day Absence",
    to_char(CASE WHEN b1.studentid = s.id THEN b1.course_name END) as "Block 1", 
    to_char(CASE WHEN b2.studentid = s.id THEN b2.course_name END) as "Block 2",
    to_char(CASE WHEN b3.studentid = s.id THEN b3.course_name END) as "Block 3", 
    ' ' as "Signature"

from students s,

//Monday Block 1 Enrollment Generator
        (select cc.studentid, 
        c.course_name, 
        cc.course_number, 
        cc.expression, 
        cc.DATEENROLLED, 
        cc.DATELEFT
        from cc cc, courses c
        where cc.EXPRESSION like '%A%'
        and cc.SCHOOLID = 6

//!!Need to enter date variable here
        and (to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') > cc.DATEENROLLED and to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') < cc.DATELEFT)
        and c.course_number = cc.course_number
        and cc.expression like '%2%') b1,

//Monday Block 2 Enrollment Generator        
        (select cc.studentid, 
        c.course_name, 
        cc.course_number, 
        cc.expression, 
        cc.DATEENROLLED, 
        cc.DATELEFT
        from cc cc, courses c
        where cc.EXPRESSION like '%A%'
        and cc.SCHOOLID = 6

//!!Need to insert date variable here
        and (to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') > cc.DATEENROLLED and to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') < cc.DATELEFT)
        and c.course_number = cc.course_number
        and cc.expression like '%4%') b2,

//Monday Block 3 Enrollment Generator
        (select cc.studentid, 
        c.course_name, 
        cc.course_number, 
        cc.expression, 
        cc.DATEENROLLED, 
        cc.DATELEFT
        from cc cc, courses c
        where cc.EXPRESSION like '%A%'
        and cc.SCHOOLID = 6

//!!Need to enter date variable here
        and (to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') > cc.DATEENROLLED and to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') < cc.DATELEFT)
        and c.course_number = cc.course_number
        and cc.expression like '%6%') b3,

//Attendance record aggregator for the day specified
        (select s1.student_number, 
        attc.DESCRIPTION
        from ATTENDANCE att, students s1, ATTENDANCE_CODE attc, CALENDAR_DAY cd
        where att.studentid = s1.id
        and ATT_MODE_CODE = 'ATT_ModeMeeting'
        and att.ATTENDANCE_CODEID = attc.ID
        and att.calendar_dayid = cd.ID

//!!Need to insert date variable here
        and to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') = cd.DATE_VALUE) satt

where s.last_name='HappyPants'

//!!Need to insert teacher variable here
and s.HOME_ROOM = 'RadTeacher'
and s.schoolid = 6
```

Comment: There are no join-conditions within the three "Blocks" and no joining them to  `students`, so you get CROSS-joins

Comment: I don't see how you're joining your B1, b2, B3, student and Satt tables together...  since you're using the older style joins, you need a where clause with `where B1.student_Id = S.StudentID and B2.StudentID = S.StudentID and B3.StudentID = S.StudentID and SATT.student_Number = S.StudentID`?  But you may be better off using the ANSII-92 style joins which use LEFT, right, INNER.  you don't HAVE TO, but I've found it easier to read and correct missing join criteria and it's been the "standard" for 24 years now.

Comment: There's also a function in Oracle called [`Pivot`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)which could be used instead of the subqueries...

Comment: (headdesk) Of course I'm getting cross joins! As soon as I LEFT JOIN those tables, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWERED (and boy do I feel silly)**

I had created a bunch of temporary tables, but (surprise, surprise) it was cross joining. I was thinking that, since there was only one specific record inside the subquery that would match, it would come out in the wash. Nope.

Adding `LEFT JOIN` properly related the data.

```
select distinct s.lastfirst as "Name", 
    s.home_room as "Teacher", 
    to_char(CASE WHEN (9000000 + satt.student_number) = s.student_number THEN satt.description END) as "School Absence",
    to_char(CASE WHEN s.student_number = satt.student_number THEN satt.description END) as "Extended Day Absence",
    to_char(CASE WHEN b1.studentid = s.id THEN b1.course_name END) as "Block 1", 
    to_char(CASE WHEN b2.studentid = s.id THEN b2.course_name END) as "Block 2",
    to_char(CASE WHEN b3.studentid = s.id THEN b3.course_name END) as "Block 3", 
    ' ' as "Signature"

from students s

//Monday Block 1 Enrollment Generator
    LEFT JOIN
        (select cc.studentid, 
        c.course_name, 
        cc.course_number, 
        cc.expression, 
        cc.DATEENROLLED, 
        cc.DATELEFT
        from cc cc, courses c
        where cc.EXPRESSION like '%A%'
        and cc.SCHOOLID = 6

//!!Need to enter date variable here
        and (to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') > cc.DATEENROLLED and to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') < cc.DATELEFT)
        and c.course_number = cc.course_number
        and cc.expression like '%2%') b1 on s.id = b1.studentid

//Monday Block 2 Enrollment Generator        
    LEFT JOIN
        (select cc.studentid, 
        c.course_name, 
        cc.course_number, 
        cc.expression, 
        cc.DATEENROLLED, 
        cc.DATELEFT
        from cc cc, courses c
        where cc.EXPRESSION like '%A%'
        and cc.SCHOOLID = 6

//!!Need to insert date variable here
        and (to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') > cc.DATEENROLLED and to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') < cc.DATELEFT)
        and c.course_number = cc.course_number
        and cc.expression like '%4%') b2 on s.id = b2.studentid

//Monday Block 3 Enrollment Generator
    LEFT JOIN
        (select cc.studentid, 
        c.course_name, 
        cc.course_number, 
        cc.expression, 
        cc.DATEENROLLED, 
        cc.DATELEFT
        from cc cc, courses c
        where cc.EXPRESSION like '%A%'
        and cc.SCHOOLID = 6

//!!Need to enter date variable here
        and (to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') > cc.DATEENROLLED and to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') < cc.DATELEFT)
        and c.course_number = cc.course_number
        and cc.expression like '%6%') b3 on s.id = b3.studentid

//Attendance record aggregator for the day specified
    LEFT JOIN
        (select s1.student_number, 
        attc.DESCRIPTION
        from ATTENDANCE att, students s1, ATTENDANCE_CODE attc, CALENDAR_DAY cd
        where att.studentid = s1.id
        and ATT_MODE_CODE = 'ATT_ModeMeeting'
        and att.ATTENDANCE_CODEID = attc.ID
        and att.calendar_dayid = cd.ID

//!!Need to insert date variable here
        and to_timestamp('19-SEP-2016') = cd.DATE_VALUE) satt on s.student_number = satt.student_number

where s.last_name='HappyPants'

//!!Need to insert teacher variable here
//and s.HOME_ROOM = 'RadTeacher'
and s.schoolid = 6
order by lastfirst
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is doing a cross join that's why you are getting multiple rows. Try using INNER JOIN instead

Comment: It's gotta be an OUTER JOIN because there will always be Student records, but not always Enrollment records. If a NULL exists, it has to show up.